# rpmbuild install: cannot create directory

Tags: packaging, rpm

I'm creating an RPM file but when using install I get some permission errors.

This is my spec file:

```
%define buildroot %{_tmppath}/nagios-1-1-root-%(%{__id_u} -n)

Summary: Nagios blabla
Name: nagios
Version: 1
Release: 1
License: PROPRIETARY
Group: Applications/Accessories
Source: nagios-1.tar.gz
Packager: Nicholas Lievens <lievens.nicholas@gmail.com>
AutoReqProv: no
Requires: gcc gcc-c++ glibc glibc-common glibc-devel gd gd-devel php53 php53-cli php53-mysql php53-gd php53-pdo graphviz httpd libdbi-dbd-mysql libdbi-devel mysql mysql-server mysql-devel git

%description
Nagios!
%prep
%setup

%build
./configure --with-init-dir=/etc/init.d --with-nagios-user=nagios --with-nagios-group=nagios
make all

%install
make install DESTDIR=${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}
make install-init DESTDIR=${RPM_BUILD_ROOT} 
make install-config DESTDIR=${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}
make install-commandmode DESTDIR=${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}
make install-webconf DESTDIR=${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}
make install-devel DESTDIR=${RPM_BUILD_ROOT}

#htpasswd -b -c /usr/local/nagios/etc/htpasswd.users nagiosadmin nagiosadmin
%files
%defattr(755,root,root)
/etc/init.d/nagios
%{_prefix}/var
%{_prefix}/var/spool/checkresults
%{_prefix}/var/rw
%{_prefix}/etc
%{_prefix}/bin
%{_prefix}/sbin
%{_prefix}/libexec
%{_prefix}/lib
%{_prefix}/include/nagios
%{_prefix}/share
%{_prefix}/etc
%defattr(644,root,root)
%config(noreplace) %{_prefix}/etc/*.cfg
%defattr(750,root,nagios)
/etc/nagios
/etc/nagios/objects
%defattr(755,nagios,nagios)
/var/log/nagios
/var/log/nagios/archives
%defattr(2775,nagios,nagios)
/var/spool/nagios
###%files www
%defattr(755,root,root)
%{_prefix}/sbin
%{_prefix}/sbin/*
%{_prefix}/share/nagios
%defattr(-,root,root)
%{_prefix}/share/nagios/*
%config(noreplace) /etc/httpd/conf.d/nagios.conf
%defattr(-,root,root)
%{_prefix}/include/nagios
%{_prefix}/include/nagios/locations.h
```

Some things are commented out just for debugging reasons.Could anyone tell why I'm getting the output:

> install: cannot create directory `/var/spool/nagios': Permission
>   denied error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.80635 (%install)

Comment: Why are you overriding `%{_prefix}`?  Users who install your package will end up with nagios *installed* in `/home/mockbuild/.local/usr/local/nagios`.  Except half of the files will actually end up where you belong because you just use `/usr` instead of `%{_prefix}` in the other defines.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to build this on RHEL 5?  If so, you need to add this line somewhere in the header:

```
BuildRoot:  %{_tmppath}/%{name}-%{version}-%{release}-root-%(%{__id_u} -n)
```

Otherwise `$RPM_BUILD_ROOT` will not be populated.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I updated the code in my start post. Currently I'm struggling to run the make install-init. This requires root I think (gives the error cannot change ownership of /var/tmp/nagios-1-1-root-nagios/etc/init.d/nagios)

Comment: I've edited the Makefile.in now and change INIT OPTIONS from root to nagios. Now it continues and all the make installs succeed, but after that I get a large list of RPM Builder errors: Install (but unpackaged file(s) found: ... Does this mean there are missing files in my source?